# Android - ListAdapter - Animate ImageView within row doesn't start when row is selected

Tags: android, animation, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I am implementing a ListView with a custom ArrayAdapter in Android.  The row layout contains a TextView and an ImageView and depending on the state of the row object, I animate the ImageView.  The problem is that when I start the animation on the selected row, it doesn't actually start the animation until I select another row.  Below is a simplified version of my getView method:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View rowView = convertView;
    RowHolder holder = null;
    Item item = items.get(position);

    if(rowView == null)
    {
        rowView = _context.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.my_list, null);
        holder = new RowHolder();
        holder.title = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        holder.imageView = (ImageView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (RowHolder)rowView.getTag();
    }

    holder.title.setText(item.title);

    if(item.status == ANIMATING)
    {
        holder.imageView.setVisiblity(View.VISIBLE);
        Animation rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.button_rotate);

        holder.imageView.startAnimation(rotation);
    }
    else
    {
        holder.imageView.clearAnimation();
        holder.imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    return rowView;
}
```

Comment: where/how are you setting item.status?

Comment: I am setting item.status in another class and then calling notifyDataSetChanged on the adapter.